# what's the disadvantage of having lots of css selectors?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

What is the disadvantage of having many CSS selectors?

Are there any performance problems associated with having lots of CSS selectors? Any links/real tests?

I've found https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/css-usage/ and the only reason why i see its use is because it might help removing unused CSS classes from the final CSS so it would be smaller. But its cached by the browser anyway so i see a problem with its size.

Comment: Many CSS selectors per ruleset or many rulesets? If you're not a layout engine developer performance shouldn't matter to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has a mild effect on render performance, but the main reason for avoiding it is that it tends to be a bad smell, indicating complicated overrides between different rules, resulting in a hard-to-maintain stylesheet.